# Oauth2 - Refresh Token Flow for Sandbox

Tags: developer

Is there any other way to get refresh token in Oauth2 flow for sandbox using the same url (login.salesforce.com) as the url for production? We figured that we get 400 because we used this url and not 'test.salesforce.com' for sandbox, but is there other option to get refresh token with the regular url?

Answer (score 0):

A refresh token is as good as client credential and that it is utilized to fetch the access token once it has been expired. So you cannot fetch a refresh token from a sandbox by providing a url for production instance. You will always need to fetch it from the respective sandbox.

You will in most of the cases need to fetch the refresh token only once, and while you can have your connected app created in any org and utilize the client secret/key from there, but you will always need to authenticate the User to the respective sandbox to be able to fetch the refresh token.

You can find more details on this topic on the below links:

- [How Does the OAuth Refresh Token Fit Into the Authentication Flow?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm)
- [OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5)